# Meaning of columns from ps

Tags: linux, bash, ps

In Linux bash, what do the four columns mean from `ps`?

e.g

```
PID   TTY         TIME CMD
15286 pts/498 00:00:00 bash
30887 pts/498 00:00:00 ps
```

Comment: `ps` is not a shell built-in - it has nothing to do with bash.  If in doubt do a `type ps`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `man` page:

> It displays the process ID (pid=PID), the terminal associated with the process (tname=TTY), the cumulated CPU time in [dd-]hh:mm:ss format (time=TIME), and the executable name (ucmd=CMD).